# Is this a CGI issue? MapServer error (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, mapserver

I just installed MapServer 6.4.1 in Linux Mint and got this error (Opera dragonify) after passing an url in my localhost:

url: localhost/ms?LAYERS=Temp2014&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=-10635414.142106,-2285406.7635122,-6619106.9284492,160578.14127299&WIDTH=821&HEIGHT=500

```
PNG
IHDR5ôÇÔNIDATxíÁ1Â õOm O àc{÷C·IEND®B`
```

[image]

I use gdal-1.11.2 (installed from source) and MapServer was installed with apt-get (UbuntuGis stable). In my Synaptic Package Manager I found 'libgdal1h', not sure if this would be related. Apache version here:

```
apache2                                     2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server 
apache2-bin                                 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server (binary files and modules) 
apache2-data                                2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4                                    all          Apache HTTP Server (common files) 
apache2-utils                               2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server (utility programs for web servers) 
libapache2-mod-mapcache                     1.2.1-2                                             amd64        tile caching server - Apache module 
libapache2-mod-perl2                        2.0.8+httpd24-r1449661-6ubuntu2                     amd64        Integration of perl with the Apache2 web server 
libapache2-mod-php5                         5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9                               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module) 
libapr1:amd64                               1.5.0-1                                             amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Library 
libaprutil1:amd64                           1.5.3-1                                             amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library 
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64               1.5.3-1                                             amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - SQLite3 Driver 
libaprutil1-ldap:amd64                      1.5.3-1                                             amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - LDAP Driver 
libsvn1:amd64                               1.8.8-1ubuntu3.1                                    amd64        Shared libraries used by Apache Subversion
```

Any hints are appreciated, thanks in advance,

Comment: Btw, if I use shp2img I get an empty PNG, so this would tell me that CGI may not be the issue, I am wondering if my postgis connection would be the problem here, any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: what does this url return? `http://localhost/wms?`. It should return something as `QUERY STRING is empty` or similar. Can you please add more details, i.e your map file

Comment: hi thanks, it gives `No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.`, so mapserver should be working correctly, my MAP file has `OUTPUTFORMAT NAME "png" DRIVER "AGG/PNG" MIMETYPE "image/png" IMAGEMODE RGBA EXTENSION "png" FORMATOPTION "INTERLACE=OFF" END` and my WMS layer has `transparent: true, format: 'image/png'`. Indeed I found a MIME TYPE message in Firebug saying that the PNG is not recognized as image, does that make sense? I mean, my MAP setting works well in my laptop also under the same ubuntu+mapserver+openlayers versions, that's funny.